# Change index URL with parameters using htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I want my URL index to work with or without parameter at the end:

**mysite.com** need to works exactly the same as **mysite.com/test**

Because I need to get the `test` variable with GET. But the site needs to behave equally with or without this parameter. I try:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?var=$1
```

But it breaks the links to the exters files (css, jquery, etc.).

Comment: Are your asset files using relative or absolute urls? If they are relative. Try adding this code `<base href="/" />` to the <head> section of your html. Then test your rewrites.

Comment: The directive as posted would break _everything_, not just links to "exters files", since it would result in a rewrite-loop for every request (500 Internal Server Error response).

Answer (score 1):

I got it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) index.php?var=$1
```